# Having JQuery/JS submit a Ruby on Rails button after finishing, as compared to submitting a rails form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

So basically on one page I have a Rails form that has a JQuery link on it, and in the JQuery handler i have the line

```
        $('#form_name').get(0).submit();
```

which submits the Rails form after the JavaScript work is done.

the button is part of the each loop, being used to call a method on the current post:

```
        <td><%= button_to 'Renew', [:renew, post], method: :post %></td>
```

My question is, on a different page, I have a button that I want called instead of the form. What is the correct JQuery/JS for that? Thank you

Comment: Question about button is incomplete. Need more specifics about purpose and some html for the button

Comment: so you want that, when you click on a button in index.html u actually click a button in edit.html ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a CSS selector for any object.  For example:

```
<button class="my-target">Label</button>
```

and with jQuery you can:

```
$('.my-target').click();
```

To your button you can add a class attribute

```
<%= button_to 'Renew', [:renew, post], method: :post, class: 'my-target' %>
```